# How to hide hyperlinks in Partial View depending on value returned from Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have these 2 lines in the .cshtml:

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("GetAllVehicleLocations", "VehicleReporting", new { @class = "page-scroll" })">All Vehicle Locations</a></li>

<li><a href="@Url.Action("GetToBeDoneVehicles", "VehicleReporting", new { @class = "page-scroll" })">To Be Done Vehicles</a></li>
```

I want to hide these hyperlinks depending on a value returned from the Controller. The value is a ClientID. If ClientID = 1 then hide the links else leave them visible.

I have tried various different implementations, below being my last.

.cshtml:

```
if (@Html.Action("GetSelectedClientID", "VehicleReporting") != 1)
{
   <li><a href="@Url.Action("GetAllVehicleLocations", "VehicleReporting", new {@class = "page-scroll"})">All Vehicle Locations</a></li>
   <li><a href="@Url.Action("GetToBeDoneVehicles", "VehicleReporting", new {@class = "page-scroll"})">To Be Done Vehicles</a></li>
}
```

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetSelectedClientID()
{
   selectedClientId = HelperMethods.GetClientId();
   return PartialView(selectedClientId);
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Please note that I'm new to MVC!

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller should return plain text in that case or you could return json and use an ajax call for that, but the following should keep you going:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetSelectedClientID()
{
   var selectedClientId = HelperMethods.GetClientId().ToString();
   return Content(selectedClientId);
}
```

and now in view you can check for the returned string value:

```
@if(Html.Action("GetSelectedClientID", "VehicleReporting").ToString() != "1")
{
   <li><a href="@Url.Action("GetAllVehicleLocations", "VehicleReporting", new {@class = "page-scroll"})">All Vehicle Locations</a></li>
   <li><a href="@Url.Action("GetToBeDoneVehicles", "VehicleReporting", new {@class = "page-scroll"})">To Be Done Vehicles</a></li>
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer worked after I changed to this line `string selectedClientId = HelperMethods.GetClientId().ToString();` and also removed the `@` symbol from before the `if`. Please amend your answer and then I will mark it as accepted

Comment: updated it @RMadd but i believe we need to prefix `@` to start writing c# code in view

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned the code is already inside another `if` block which is prefixed with `@`

Comment: @RMadd for future readers it would look wrong answer as it stands right now, as `@` is missing

Comment: OK then re-add the `@`symbol. As it will be much less readable if I add in the full code block. We can both then delete all of these comments to clean up

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to conditionally hide parts of your view depending on a value.

You could use `ViewData` dictionary in your main action:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
   ViewData["selectedClientId"] = HelperMethods.GetClientId();
   return View();
}
```

And in your view check its value this way:

```
@if (ViewData["selectedClientId"] != 1)
{
   <li><a href="@Url.Action("GetAllVehicleLocations", "VehicleReporting", new {@class = "page-scroll"})">All Vehicle Locations</a></li>
   <li><a href="@Url.Action("GetToBeDoneVehicles", "VehicleReporting", new {@class = "page-scroll"})">To Be Done Vehicles</a></li>
}
```